# Remove top gray line on UITableViewCell

Tags: uitableview

I have a UITableViewCell and I want to remove the gray line on the top of it. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me, it seems to be a problem with the image tiling.  I'm tiling a 320x480 image and there is a gray line at the break at the top as well as 480 pixels from the top.  I'm setting my background like this:

self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"mybackground.png"]];

Cropping the image seemed to remove the gray line so I think it had something to do with the image itself.

Answer (score 4):

use this to set the separator color to clear:

```
tableView.separatorColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

Comment: but I just it on a single cell. and I only want the top line gone. (it is the first cell in the table)

Comment: Did you finally manage to get rid of that grey line ? I'm having the same problem on the top of the first cell only.

Answer (score 4):

BTW this is arguably a bit better solution than setting the separator color to clear...

```
tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;
```

Answer (score 1):

I know it is too late to answer this question. However, in **swift 3** solution is:

```
tableView.separatorStyle = .none
```

Answer (score 0):

return 0 from heightForHeaderInSection. Or delete this macro.

Thanks