# gray line on top of UITableView iOS 5

Tags: uitableview, ios5, three20

A strange gray line has appeared on the top of my UITableView in iOS 5 (was never present until I upgraded to Xcode 4.3 and am running app on iOS 5 iPhone) - has anyone else seen this?  I was also getting funny white lines in some of my other TableViewControllers that I got rid of by doing this:

```
    // needed to get rid of funny white lines in iOS 5
    tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleSingleLine;
tableView.separatorColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

However, this does not work to remove this line.  There is no header title here. The line scrolls up and down with my UITableView 
    [image: settings]

Comment: Try this:
tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;

Comment: thanks for the quick response - unfortunately that did not work and the line is still there

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem, but only it appears in Edit mode.
I was need header, so previous answer not for me.
But this answer help for me [Remove top gray line on UITableViewCell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6417363/remove-top-gray-line-on-uitableviewcell)
, i hope it helps some one, who encountered with same problem.

```
tableView.separatorColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably are implementing the heightForHeaderInSection method.
Either delete it completely or return 0.

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 0.0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you had a simple background changing `colorWithPatternImage` with `colorWithRed:green:blue:alpha` will do the trick.

```
//self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"background"]];
self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed: green: blue: alpha:]
```

But for a background like this, if you can crop the background.png image in a way that tilted images make up the whole background, will remove the line on top.